# Jquery Ui Datepicker table enormously larger then expect, how to resolve this issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-datepicker

[This is a picture of how large the calendar is coming out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx7p0.png)

I have cheeked the CSS in inspect mode to find a class or ID that may adjut it but unsuccessful but after trying every size nothing has adjusted the size, and the interesting thing is the number button dates do not adjust at all I was able to bring the box to the size of the textbox but not circle buttons did not move from its size at all. Please help if anyone has the solution to this.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pickupDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @placeholder = "Select Date..." } })

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.dropoffDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker2", @placeholder = "Select Date..." } })
```

```
                <script>

                    $(function () {
                        $(".datepicker2").datepicker({

                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            // showOn: "both",
                            // buttonImage: "/images/cal.png",
                            //buttonImageOnly: true

                        });
                        $(".datepicker").datepicker({

                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            // showOn: "both",
                            //  buttonImage: "/images/cal.png",
                            //  buttonImageOnly: true
                        });

                    });
```

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question. We don't debug images.

Comment: @BStill I have shared the code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself!

if your caldender is coming out large like mine did then inspect the page and you find this
id="ui-datepicker-div" and class=".ui-state-default"  then just adjust to whatever size you want. like i did this size.

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    font-size: 12px;
    width:300px;
}
.ui-state-default{
    width:35px;
}
```

[Much better size in this link check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Naisx.png)